# How to identify android Marker in click listener

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I have a google map in an android application, using API V2, and I've run into a slight problem.  I'm loading all Markers in the visible map area from a database.  That part is running fine, as is clicking them, and clicking their info windows.

The problem is, once I have the info window click event captured, I want to send the represented database object to another activity.  How do I get that.  I was thinking latlng of the marker, but it appears to have been adjusted/truncated when put on the map.  So I was thinking of using the name of the building, but what if two buildings have the same name.  I was thinking subclassing Marker and giving mine an id, but Marker is a final class.

For now I'm going to settle on a name/address kind of search, but I'd prefer something a little more definitive to the specific object the marker represents.  How do I store extra data in a marker?

Comment: Hi Did you get the solutions?

Comment: I ended up testing the lat lon of the clicked marker against the lat lon of my data objects.